# How do I insert the row_number variable inside the python 3.7 sqlite3 query?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a python-3.7 function like below. My sqlite3 table has 10 columns. I want to get the data entry from the table by row number. But the row_number is a variable and not a constant. How do I insert the row_number variable inside the python 3.7 sqlite3 query? The problem is here in the code after rowid = 1 is a constant. I don't want that. I want it to be variable.

```
def readSqliteTable(row_number):
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('SQLite_Python.db');
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor();
        print("Connected to SQLite");

        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * FROM SqliteDb_Addresser WHERE rowid = 1""";
        # How do I insert row_number variable in the above sqlite3 query?
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query);
        records = cursor.fetchall();
        print("Total rows are:  ", len(records));
        print("Printing each row");
        for row in records:
            aTuple = (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[8], row[9], row[10]);



        cursor.close();
        return aTuple;

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to read data from sqlite table", error);

    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close();
            print("The SQLite connection is closed");
            return -1;
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `sqlite_select_query = "SELECT * FROM SqliteDb_Addresser WHERE rowid = ?";`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you'd call a **parameterized query**, and the explanation is [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html). Long story short, you want something like this:

```py
sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * FROM SqliteDb_Addresser WHERE rowid = ?""";
cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query, variable_row_id);
```

However, using an ORM such as SQL Alchemy is a much more pleasant experience, consider trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want something like -

```
sqlite_select_query = "SELECT * FROM SqliteDb_Addresser WHERE rowid = ?;"
cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query, (1,))
```

If you want to get the row id value from a variable, the it would be like -

```
row_id = 1
cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query, (row_id,))
```

You can always get the rowids present in your table using a query like -
`SELECT rowid FROM SqliteDb_Addresser`. And then you can loop over it and fetch all the rows corresponding to that rowid value.